How to find arbitrage in a one period binomial model?
Here is the setup:
one period binomial model
The market has three assets: bank account $B$, asset $S$, and asset $K$
$r = 0$, so payoff for asset invested at bank at any $t$ is $1$
$S_0 = 100, S_u = 120$ and $S_d = 80.$
$K_0 = 10, K_u = 15$ and $K_d = 5$
Lets say $K_u$ is different and I want to find a type 1 (type A) arbitrage.
How can I do this? I know that there are certain conditions for type 1, $V_0=0, p(V_t \ge 0) = 1$ and $p(V_T > 0)$
So
$V_T = a + b K_T + c S_T$
$V_0 = a + b K_0 + c S_0 = a + 10b + 100c$
So what does it mean to "find" a type 1 arbitrage? Does it mean to construct a portfolio? So am I finding the values of $a,b,c$?
I can let $V_0 = 0$, so this is one equation and I guess I need $V_T$ (up and down case) to be $ V_T \ge 0$? But in this case my up case for K_T is some deterministic $x \ne 15$. How do I formulate this problem?
Does this approach make sense? Am I understanding the problem?

To answer this question properly, I think there needs to be a little more information. For example, when S goes up, does K also go up? (for example, is K a derivative on S?) If that is the case (ie if S going up means K goes up), and for example $K_u = 20$, then you could for example set up this system of linear equations:
$$xB_0 + yS_0 + zK_0 = 0$$
$$xB_1 + yS_d + zK_d = 0$$
$$xB_1 + yS_u + zK_u = 1$$

As a side note, I suggest you revisit your definitions -- I am not familiar with "type 1" etc  but i found a conflicting definition online (https://coral.ise.lehigh.edu/~ted/files/ie447/lectures/Lecture6.pdf) and you seem to be missing a term in the last part, $P(V_T > 0) > 0$ or something similar

@Rylan My guess is that he either didn’t notice, or forgot to include an option’s position in the portfolio.

If $K_u$ is lower that 10 (let's say 9), you have an arbitrage (not sure about the type convention). And from one arbitrage, you can create infinite others.
At 0, sell 1 unit of K and buy 10 units of B (assuming $B_0=1$, but its value is irrelevant), total cost of this is 0.
At time 1, $10B$ are worth 10 and $-1K$ is worth either $-5$ or $-9$.
So the PV of your portfolio is either $1$ or $5$.
So, you paid nothing and got $1$ or $5$ after one period: arbitrage!
The absence of arbitrage in a binomial model (any dimension) is
$A_d \le A_0 (1+r) \le A_u$
for every asset $A$.
